Eclipse snap won't start
Today my eclipse snap randomly did not open anymore. When I start eclipse in the terminal I get this output:
To override eclipse.ini, copy the default file to '/home/myname/snap/eclipse/106 eclipse.ini' and modify to suit.
/snap/eclipse/106/bin/eclipse-wrapper: line 9: /snap/eclipse/106/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse: Permission denied
/snap/eclipse/106/bin/eclipse-wrapper: line 9: exec: /snap/eclipse/106/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse: cannot execute: Permission denied

Reinstalling doesn't change anything. java --version outputs this:
java 23.0.1 2024-10-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 23.0.1+11-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0.1+11-39, mixed mode, sharing)

javac --version outputs this:
javac 23.0.1

edit: It seems this error is a bug of the new update

Youŕe not alone in this. I have the same issue since today, running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS with openjdk version "21.0.5" 2024-10-15. Looks to me like a problem introduced by an update.

How about switching to the apt version of eclipse?

I cant find an apt version of eclipse

This worked for me:
snap revert eclipse
